# Getting parent form name of a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form (form3)which could be opened from two other forms. Form1 and Form2.

how can I get which one is the parent of the form3?

Comment: How do you "open" form3? How and where is form3 instantiated and how is it referenced from form1 and form2? Some source code would be helpful.

Comment: Please, do not include IDE tag (Visual Studio) among tags if your question is not directly about it and you just write code in it. Problems with code are seldom connected to a code editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "parent" has a very strict definition in Windows.  The Form class derives from Control like all UI classes do, but it is pretty distinct, it is a top-level window.  Very unlike the other controls, like Button and TextBox, they are child windows inside a parent window.  The parent of a Form is the desktop window, pretty unlikely that you are interested in that one.

So it is pretty meaningless to talk about "the parent of Form3", it is the same parent as Form1 and Form2 and it doesn't help you at all to distinguish which one might have displayed the Form3 window.

Windows does have a way to associate two top-level windows with each other, it has the notion of an *owner window*.  It is meant to implement a tool window or a dialog, an owned window is always displayed on top of its owner and is minimized along with its owner.  Creating an owned window is simple:

```
   var toolWindow = new Form3();
   toolWindow.Show(this);
```

This Show() overload takes an argument that indicates its owner, *this* can be a reference to a Form1 or Form2 object, depending on where this code appears.  Inside the Form3 class, you can find the owner back by using the *Owner* property.

Which is fairly unlikely what you are really talking about, Winforms is frequently a programmer's first introduction to object-oriented programming and dealing with object references is often confounding.  If you need a reference to a *logical* parent in Form3 then just write the code so you pass that parent.  Which you do by giving the Form3 class a constructor:

```
   private Form logicalParent;

   public Form3(Form parent) {
       InitializeComponent();
       logicalParent = parent;
   }
```

And creating the window in Form1 or Form2 just takes:

```
   var form = new Form3(this);
   form.Show();
```

You can further improve this code in an object-oriented way by designing a base class for Form1 and Form2, one that has members in common that a class like Form3 would be interested in.  Or better yet, an interface that both Form1 and Form2 implement, that reduces the coupling significantly.  Last but not least, use *events* to allow Form3 to notify its logical parent.  Probably what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the Parent form from the Child like this,

Say MainForm is the Form1

```
MainForm parent = (MainForm)this.Owner;
```

Or If you want to find the Parent from the hierarchy,

In the Form1 you instantiate Form2 somewhere and pass it a reference to Form1 in ctor:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
```

In the class definition of Form2 add a field:

```
private Form1 m_form = null;
```

In the constructor of the second form set that field:

```
public Form2(Form1 f)
{
   m_form = f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Form3 you can do this:

```
    var form1 = this.Parent as Form1;
    if(form1 != null)
    {
       //form1.Text
    }


    var form2 = this.Parent as Form2;
    if(form2 != null)
    {
       //form2.Text
    }
```

Comment: Why check all `is`, `as` and `!=null`? Last two are enough. Don't use `is` here at all.

Comment: This is assuming that `form3` is inserted in the `Controls` collection of either `form1` or `form2`. Normally "open" a form don't needs to do that, you only use the `Show` method of `form3` somewhere in the other forms.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I get a name of Parent of **control** via

```
MessageBox.Show(control_Name.Parent.Name);
```

but now we are finding the Parent of a form, so we cannot use the same method because we don't even need to have real Parent and Client relationship to call a Form. So we will have **NullReferenceException** when we do

```
MessageBox.Show(this.Parent.Name);
```

in Form3.

By doing these in Form 1 and Form2 and Form3, I can call the Form3 from both forms.

### Form1

```
    Form3 frm3;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm3 = new Form3(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm3.Show();
    }
```

### Form2

```
    Form3 frm3;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm3 = new Form3(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm3.Show();
    }
```

### Form3

```
    public Form3(Form parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

As my conclusion, if the Parent form **can only have one**, then both of Form1 and Form2 is **not** Form3 parent Form because either one is not exist but the other one still can call Form3 out. If the Parent form can have **more than one**, then I think **both of** Form1 and Form2 are parent forms of Form3.

---

By the way, **if the Parent Form minimized, the Child Form also minimized**, then we can make Form1 as Parent Form (or actually **owner form**) of Form3

### Form1

```
    Form3 frm3;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm3 = new Form3(this);
        this.AddOwnedForm(frm3);
    }
```

### OR

we set the **owner** of Form3 to the **Form who calling** it by

### Form3

```
    public Form3(Form parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Owner = parent;
    }
```

If you are not agree with me, please give me **clear definition** of **Parent form** and **Child form**.thanks. I try to explain from my point of view and hope someone correct me if I am wrong.